# Converting dataframe column to datetime result to TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'int'>

Tags: python, dataframe, python-datetime

I am trying to extract date and time from one column of data frame. The name of the data frame is df_BA_new and the corresponding column is 1. Below you can see the column 1

```
0         200604281300
1         200604281330
2         200604281335
3         200604281350
4         200604281355
    
392395    202209161320
392396    202209161325
392397    202209161330
392398    202209161335
392399    202209161340
Name: 1, Length: 392400, dtype: object
```

I try to convert data on this column to date time using the code shown below

`df_BA_new[1] = pd.to_datetime(df_BA_new[1],format="%Y%m%d%H%M")`

However, I take the following error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 30
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Make sure that someone else can copy and paste the code from the question, without changing anything, and immediately see the exact error you describe. Make sure that you show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like multi-line code. Finally, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that others do not have to fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to improve the post

Answer (score 0):

This example might help;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [200604281300, 200604281330, 200604281335]}) # example dataframe
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
df
```

Output

```
0   2006-04-28 13:00:00
1   2006-04-28 13:30:00
2   2006-04-28 13:35:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but the the code that I posted `df_BA_new[1] = pd.to_datetime(df_BA_new[1],format="%Y%m%d%H%M")`

 look similar to the one above `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y%m%d%H%M')` , may I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You almost there You need to convert type `object` to `int64`. It throwing error because you trying to give a `object` dtype as a input to `pd`. it must need `int` as input. For `int`  too long we are uisng `int64`.

```
df_BA_new[1]=df_BA_new[1].astype(str).astype('int64')

df_BA_new[1] = pd.to_datetime(df_BA_new[1],format="%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Comment: unfortunately again the same error occured

Comment: Try now..I just edited & Let me know.

Comment: The first line works as expected df_BA_new[1] is now int64 but the second line: `df_BA_new[1] = pd.to_datetime(df_BA_new[1],format="%Y%m%d%H%M")` result to the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but adding errors='coerce' argument solved the problem. There was no missing data on the column that is why I did not understand what was the problem.

`df_BA_new[1] =pd.to_datetime(df_BA_new[1],errors='coerce',format="%Y%m%d%H%M")`

Comment: I finally resolved the issue the .csv file that I used to build the data frame had some missing lines data that I missed out (just around 20 lines in a total of 400000 columns). Thank you again for all the helps